# Webpack 5 does not inject bundle into index.html

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm, webpack

I'm having issues understanding why my webpack bundle isn't injected into my index.html. I have recently upgraded webpack from 4 to 5. Everything works locally.

The following steps are taken:

1. Jenkins builds my project
2. A resulting WAR file is uploaded to a repository
3. The index.html in the WAR file doesn't contain the webpack bundle.

I will try my best to supply all information needed. If something is missing, please let me know.

This is what the final WAR file looks like (where main.js is the webpack bundle):

[image]

The index.html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv" role="main">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>FAST2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="appmaincontainer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a webpack.config.js and a webpack.production.config.js which are identical:

```
const path = require('path')

/* Utilities */
const webpackHtml = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpackBundleAnalyzer = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/main/webapp/index'],
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                    'eslint-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash:8]',
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpackHtml({
            hash: true,
            template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpackBundleAnalyzer({
            openAnalyzer: false
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/resources/*': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8080/fenix/',
                secure: false,
                onError: error => { console.log('::PROXY ERROR::', error) }
            }
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@actions': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/actions'),
            '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/components'),
            '@gui': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/gui'),
            '@functions': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/functions'),
            '@middleware': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/middleware'),
            '@reducers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/reducers'),
            '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/styles'),
        }
    }
}
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config webpack.production.config.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.18.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-markdown": "^7.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.6.0",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.5",
    "acorn": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.2.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.14.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.5",
    "file-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "jest": "^27.2.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^5.58.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^lodash-es$": "lodash"
    },
    "verbose": true,
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/test/webapp/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/main/webapp/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!src/main/webapp/showcase/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/vendor/**"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/test/webapp/**/*.test.js?(x)"
    ]
  }
}
```

For Jenkins to build my project I have the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Maven build') {
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
                sh './jenkins_build.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('Node build') {
            steps {
                sh 'cd webapp/jenkins-build && ./build.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('Restore file ownership') {
            steps {
                sh 'sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins .'
            }
        }
        stage('Nexus deploy') {
            steps {
                sh './nexus_deploy.sh'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Node build stage runs the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf *.war
WAR_FILE_NAME=(../target/*.war)
echo "Using war-file $WAR_FILE_NAME"
docker run --rm --network host --name myProject-node-build -v "$PWD"/../:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app/jenkins-build/ node:14.18.3-buster ./run.sh
cp -v $WAR_FILE_NAME .
WAR_FILE_NAME=(*.war)
if [[ ! -f $WAR_FILE_NAME ]] ; then
    echo 'File $WAR_FILE_NAME was not found - aborting.'
    exit 1
fi
echo "Packaging node-artifacts in the war-file"
cd ../dist
zip -vu ../jenkins-build/$WAR_FILE_NAME *.css
zip -vu ../jenkins-build/$WAR_FILE_NAME *.html
zip -vu ../jenkins-build/$WAR_FILE_NAME *.js
zip -vur ../jenkins-build/$WAR_FILE_NAME fonts
cd ../jenkins-build
```

The shell script run.sh ran by docker looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/src/app/
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf dist
mkdir node_modules
chmod 777 node_modules
NPM_VERSION=$(npm -v)
NODE_VERSION=$(nodejs -v)
echo "Using node version $NODE_VERSION and npm version $NPM_VERSION"
echo "Installing webpack"
npm install webpack
echo "Installing babel"
npm install babel
echo "Installing dependencies"
npm install
echo "Builds installation"
npm run deploy
echo "Copies generated file from container"
cp -v src/main/webapp/bundle.app.js /usr/src/app/
```